# How to set an image strip (ImageSequence) length via python?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I have this piece of code which creates an image strip but I can't find the way how to set the length of that:

```
img_strip = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image(
name = img_name, 
filepath = img_filepath, 
channel = 5, 
frame_start = 1500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `frame_offset_start` to change length from left side and `frame_offset_left` to change length from right side. Building on your code

```
img_strip = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image(
name = img_name, 
filepath = img_filepath, 
channel = 5, 
frame_start = 1500)

img_strip.frame_offset_start = 10
img_strip.frame_offset_end = -20 # Not sure why but blender needs this value negative. 
#If you put positive value strip will end up in negative side of frames.

#img_strip.frame_start = 20
```

There is also `frame_start` setting it does not change the length of the strip but put it at given frame

Answer (score 0):

Use : **frame_final_duration**

```
img_strip.frame_final_duration=frames_length
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Sequence.html#bpy.types.Sequence.frame_final_duration